# Evaluating a SmoothKernelDistribution at a point

Tags: probability-or-statistics

I would like to evaluate the value of the following SmoothKernelDistribution at the location, say, 2.35. What is the right way to do it?

```
data1 = {1, 2, 3};
DD = SmoothKernelDistribution[data1, 0.5];
Plot[PDF[DD, x], {x, -2, 10}]
```

Comment: You mean `PDF[DD, 2.35]`?

Comment: pretty much yes. actually to measure the area under the curve where the values are above 2.35

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To "measure the area under the curve where the values are above 2.35", evalute

```
1. - CDF[DD, 2.35]
```

> 0.382878

This is the same as

```
NIntegrate[PDF[DD, x], {x, 2.35, ∞}]
```

> 0.382878

Answer (score 3):

Just for variety also:

```
SurvivalFunction[DD, 2.35]
```

yields...

0.382878